# Need to reduce: $ \frac{(3-h) (3+h)}{h - 3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that the answer is $-(3 + h)$, but I'm not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that $(h-3)=-(3-h)$. Do you see what to do now?

Comment: So, I can now cancel that with the (3 - h) and am left with (3 + h)/-1, which is -( 3 + h ).  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since your fraction is $\dfrac {(3-h)(3+h)}{h - 3}$ and the two terms $3-h$ in the numerator and $h-3$ in the denominator are only different in a minus sign, they'll be cancelled out and the term in numerator remains which is $3+h$ multiplying by a minus sign.